# Maintain web.config file after Upgrading existing web application

Tags: asp.net, web-setup-project

I have a web project,that i am giving to client as setup package.My next release i don't want to overwrite web.config.That is i need to maintain the existing web.config.How can i do that?

Comment: Your Problem is not clear.  in one project you can have more then one web.config. you can create another one for your next release in separate folder

Comment: No.We are going to install in the same folder.So we don't to rewrite the existing web.config

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871108/maintaining-web-config-files